# NServiceBus, subscriber stop receiving messages after a period of time

Tags: nservicebus, subscriber

Using version 2.5.0.1446, my server will receive messages for about 5 - 10 minutes, after which, it will no longer receive, however this is only occurring on one environment a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.  It has been running continuously on other R2 boxes with no problem.
Logging shows that the message which were received completed successfully - so it hasn't locked on a message. When restarted the subscriber will pick up and process all outstanding messages which have built up.  Running as a service or as a console app makes no difference.

Anyone come across anything similar?

Comment: Are the messages being delivered to its queue successfully during that period of time?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Comment: No, it just sort of went away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a bit like another thread here:
[NService bus message delay problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758405/nservice-bus-message-delay-problem)

To provided solution was to configure the timeout settings for the messages.

Comment: We have gone live now with no problems on that server.  This doesn't sound quite right, but looks like a good starting point, thank you.